# To add noise to a sine function

Tags: python

I want to know how to output the sine function with a magnitude of **[-0.25 0.25]** plus noise with **an average of 0** and **a standard deviation of 3**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
x1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*x)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.plot(x,x1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the noise to the `x1` values

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, 3, len(x))
plt.plot(x, x1+noise)
plt.show()
```

(the noise `np.random.normal(0, 3, len(x))` is normally distributed with mean 0, see [`np.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) and it's an array of the same length as `x1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create random noise signal with np.random.normal and add it to the signal

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, 3, len(x1))
final = x1 + noise

plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.plot(x,final)
plt.show()
```